# Customize legend marker facecolor in scatterplot with patches

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

I have a scatter plot that also contains an ellipse. However, the legend only contains the formatting from the Ellipse. How can I also reflect the formatting from the scatter plot?

In the example below, I'd like the legend markers to be filled just like in the scatter plot.

```
x = np.random.randn(60) 
y = np.random.randn(60)

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
sb.scatterplot(x, y,color='red', ax=ax)
ellipse = matplotlib.patches.Ellipse( 
                xy=(0, 0), width=2, height=3, angle=45, 
                edgecolor='red', facecolor='none'
            )
ax.add_patch(ellipse)

ax.legend(['A'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib's standard way is to assign a label to each item to appear in the legend. Only in case the standard way wouldn't give the desired result, the legend can be [customized](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html).

Calling `ax.legend()` without parameters creates the default legend. Customized handles can be created with `Patch' and` Line2D` as in the code below.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.randn(60)
y = np.random.randn(60)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(x, y, color='red', ax=ax, label='scatter dots')
ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(0, 0), width=2, height=3, angle=45,
                  edgecolor='red', facecolor='none', label='ellipse')
ax.add_patch(ellipse)

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
new_handles = [Patch(facecolor='white', edgecolor='red', hatch='ooo'),
               Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', markerfacecolor='red', markeredgecolor='black', markersize=10, ls='')]
ax.legend(new_handles, labels)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: For some reason it is not working with my real data, but the working example works perfectly. Having said this, is there a way to change the formatting (`facecolor`, `edgecolor`) of markers in the legend independently outside of the plotting functions